# Debug the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make multilevel responsive drop down menu. the problem is that on clicking on Purchase, Sale and New menu the drop down menus are appearing but they remain open on again click. i want to show/ hide it on click like the #handle. it means that when i click to Purchase menu the relevant drop-down list should be appearing, on again click it must be shown off. The same requirements are with Sale and New menus. 
the code are below,

html:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="showing">
         <div id="handle">Menu</div>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Available Stock</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Purchase</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Purchase Return</a></li>
                        </ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sale</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Sale Return</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">New</a>
                         <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Customer</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Supplier</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Town</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Product</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening Stock</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gate Pass</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sale History</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#handle').on('click', function() {
        $('ul').toggleClass('showing');
        });
    $('ul#nav li').on('click', function() {
        $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-menu');
        });
</script>
```

css:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s;
}
ul#nav li {
    background:#fff;
    float:left;
}
ul#nav li a {
    color:black;
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background:#000;
    color:white;
}
ul#nav li .sub-list {
    float:none; 
}
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
ul#nav li:hover .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
#handle {
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {


    ul#nav li {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    ul {
        max-height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .showing {
        max-height:50em;
    }
    ul#nav li .sub-menu {
        max-height:0;   
    }
    .sub-menu {
        max-height:2em; 
    }
    #handle {
        display:block;
        background:#093;
        color:#fff;
        padding:10px;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        cursor:pointer;

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your Jquery? SO is not a code it for you site. Show us what you have attempted.

Comment: The posters JQuery is in the same code box as the HTML. So is the CSS. You have to scroll down to see it.

Comment: The solution below by @user4851193 works. Your menu jumps around a bit because when you take sub-menu off a ul it get's displayed block. If in your css you add 'ul#nav ul {position: absolute;}' then that should stop that happening. (you may need to adjust that if you have 3rd level menus to set the 3rd level ul back to position:static).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('ul#nav a').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('sub-menu');
 });
```

When you click on a link, ul tag that is next sibling of clicked link is shown.

Comment: its working good. On clicking on purchase menu the drop-down is appearing but its not automatically close when make click on sale menu. so also please help me in this regard,

Comment: If you mean only one sub menu must be shown at a time then you should remove sub-menu class from all sub menus before showing clicked menu